# Can I execute an ansible playbook inside a playbook?

Tags: ansible

I am running a playbook to provision my master, and after that I want to provision my nodes that are only accessible from the master.

If I try to execute the ansible-playbook from a task of the main playbook, the connection is refused, but if I ssh login inside the master and run the same ansible-playbook command all works fine

This is the main ansible-playbook, all tasks are executed untill it arrives the last

```
    - name: "Copy private key to Workstation"
      copy:
        src: ~/.ssh/private.pem
        dest: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
        mode: 0400

    - name: "Executing playbookNodes on Workstation"
      shell: "sudo ansible-playbook -i /home/ubuntu/inventory.yaml playbookNodes.yaml"
      tags:
        - remote_playbook
```

If I run the above code I get:

```
fatal: [workstation]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "ssh ubuntu@12.0.11.10",
    "delta": "0:00:00.065269",
    "end": "2019-07-22 16:05:31.183599",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "ssh ubuntu@12.0.11.10",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 255,
    "start": "2019-07-22 16:05:31.118330",
    "stderr": "Warning: Permanently added '12.0.11.10' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nubuntu@12.0.11.10: Permission denied (publickey).",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "Warning: Permanently added '12.0.11.10' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.",
        "ubuntu@12.0.11.10: Permission denied (publickey)."
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

but works when I run `ssh -i private.pem ubuntu@master` and inside the master `ansible-playbook -i inventory.yaml playbookNodes.yaml`

Comment: You should probably consider converting your first playbook into Python.

Answer (score 0):

I do something quite similar in a single playbook for AWS, as follows, you could change it up however you are provisioning machines:

```
- name: Provision machine
  hosts: localhost
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Provision ec2 instance
      ec2:
        // Do AWS ec2 provisioning stuff <snip>
      register: new_ec2_instances

  - name: Add new instance to host group
    add_host:
      groupname: newboxes
      hostname: "{{ item.private_ip }}"
    with_flattened: "{{ new_ec2_instances }}"

  - name: wait for ssh
    wait_for:
      host: "{{ item.private_ip }}"
      port: 22
      delay: 10
      timeout: 180
      state: started
    with_flattened: "{{ ec2.instances }}"

- name: Do stuff to new boxes
  hosts: newboxes
  roles:
    - yourplaybookNodesyamlhere
```